# Visual Studio Post Build Event Error while trying to use Confuser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, obfuscation, post-build-event

I have an error while I'm trying to send my args to Confuser.CLI.exe. Actually It works in console without any problem. But I would like to use it in Post Build Event. I don't know if there is a problem or not. Thanks for your help.

> if $(ConfigurationName)==Release( "‪‪V:\Onur\bin\Confuser.CLI.exe"
>   "$(TargetDir)Confuser.CLI.crproj" "$(TargetDir)")

**The error which I get while building**

```
Error   1   The command "V:\Onur\bin\Confuser.CLI.exe C:\Users\onur.can\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\zxasd\bin\Release\Confuser.CLI.crproj C:\Users\onur.can\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\zxasd\bin\Release\" exited with code -532462766.  zxasd
```